# Qt-server sends packages, but not all are received

Tags: c++, qt

I have a server-client communication created in Qt, with the main server function looking as following:

```
void Server::sendData(QPair<QString, QPair<QString, QVariant> > data)
{
//! [5]
    //QString data = "";
    qDebug() << "Transmitted data in send-data-function is: " + data.first + " " + data.second.first + " " + QString::number(data.second.second.toDouble());
    QPair<QString, QPair<QString, QVariant> > send_data = data;
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
    out << (quint16)0;
    out << send_data;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16)(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    if(Server::clientConnection != NULL)
    {
        //qDebug() << "New Connection: " << Server::clientConnection->peerAddress().toString() << " on Port: " << Server::clientConnection->peerPort();
        QVariant ipAddr_QVar(Server::clientConnection->peerAddress().toString());
        //qDebug() << "New qvariant: " << ipAddr_QVar;

        clientConnection->write(block);
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "No connection!";
}
```

and the main client functions looking as following:

```
Client::Client(QString purpose) : networkSession(0)
{
    Client::purpose = purpose;
    tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket;
    Client::blockSize = 0;
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readData()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(displayError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    QNetworkConfigurationManager manager;
    if (manager.capabilities() & QNetworkConfigurationManager::NetworkSessionRequired)
    {
        // Get saved network configuration
        QSettings settings(QSettings::UserScope, QLatin1String("QtProject"));
        settings.beginGroup(QLatin1String("QtNetwork"));
        const QString id = settings.value(QLatin1String("DefaultNetworkConfiguration")).toString();
        settings.endGroup();

        // If the saved network configuration is not currently discovered use the system default
        QNetworkConfiguration config = manager.configurationFromIdentifier(id);
        if ((config.state() & QNetworkConfiguration::Discovered) !=
            QNetworkConfiguration::Discovered) {
            config = manager.defaultConfiguration();
        }

        networkSession = new QNetworkSession(config, this);
        connect(networkSession, SIGNAL(opened()), this, SLOT(sessionOpened()));
    }
}

void Client::readData()
{
    QDataStream in(tcpSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_0);
    if (blockSize == 0) {
        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
            return;

        in >> blockSize;
    }
    if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
    {
        qDebug() << tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() << ' ' << blockSize;
        return;
    }
    in >> data;
    blockSize = 0;
    qDebug() << "Client got new data!";
    qDebug() << data.first << " " << " " << data.second.first << " " << data.second.second.toInt();
    emit Client::gotData(data);

}
```

Both are taken from the QT examples.
My problem now is that the debug messages from the server look like:

```
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 0"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 1"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 2"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 3"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 4"
...
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 96"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 97"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 98"
"Transmitted data in send-data-function is: STP S 99"
```

while the debug-output from the client-function looks like:

```
Client got new data!
"STP"     "S"   2
"Got the following new data: STP S 2"
Current Movement Status: 
Client got new data!
"STP"     "S"   3
Client got new data!
"STP"     "S"   4
"Got the following new data: STP S 3"
Current Movement Status: 
"Got the following new data: STP S 4"
Current Movement Status:
```

That is all I get directly in the receiving function, so I assume that the packages never arrive at the client. So I want to know if there is anything I can do to narrow possible bugs down before creating a minimum working example (after the `Server`- and `Client`-class both have a lot connections to the outside).

Comment: We need to see the declaration of `Client::blocksize`.

Comment: @KubaOber: `Client::blocksize` is a `quint16`-datatype

Comment: "I assume that the packages never arrive at the client", note that TCP is reliable byte stream protocol: It does not transmit packets (as far as the application is concerned), and it will not lose bytes in between (connection will eventually break, instead of missing bytes or bytes in wrong order).

Answer (score 1):

First step, like with *any* IO related problems, add error checking, something like:

```
...
in >> data;
qDebug() << "in status after data read:" << in.status();
Q_ASSERT(in.status() == QDataStream::Ok);
...
```

And same after the other read.

---

Then, the length check before `in>>data` looks suspicious, it may try to read before there's enough data. But, I advice against using `QDataStream` on a socket entirely with complex data, because it does not recover from errors, including simply too little data yet.

Instead, do this:

- On sender side, use `QDataStream` to write to a `QByteArray`, so you got a complete blob of data in the `QDataStream` format. Then send the length and contents of the byte array directly over the socket.
- On receiving end, receive the length then receive and put to a `QByteArray` that many bytes. You should now have identical byte array as on sender side. Then simply use `QDataStream` on that byte array, which is guaranteed to contain valid data (as long as you have same `QByteArray` options set on both sides, of course).

You can use `QDataStream` to send and receive the length, because it is short and of known length, but the more complex and long data is better written directly as raw bytes.

Comment: I am not quite sure how I should change my code above: As far as I can see, I am not using a QDataStream to send the size to the receiver, but I am using an QByteArray for transmitting both the size of the data and the data itself. Furthermore, I do not get any errors from in.status()